# How to test an HTTP function which takes folder as an input?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I have an HTTP handler function (POST) which allows a user to upload a folder from a web browser application. The folder is passed from JavaScript code as an array of files in a folder and on the backend (Go API) it is accepted as a `[]*multipart.FileHeader`. I am struggling in writing a Go unit test for this function. How can I pass a folder as input from a test function? I need help in creating the `httpRequest` in the right format.

I have tried to use / set values for an array of `FileHeader`, but some attributes are not allowed to be imported. So there must be a different way of testing this handler that I am not aware of.

Handler Function for folder upload:

```golang
func FolderUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) { 
// SOME LOGIC

files := r.MultipartForm.File["multiplefiles"] // files is of the type []*multipart.FileHeader

// SOME LOGIC TO PARSE THE FILE NAMES TO RECREATE THE SAME TREE STRUCTURE ON THE SERVER-SIDE AND STORE THEM AS A FOLDER
```

Unit Test function for the same handler:

```golang
func TestFolderUpload(t *testing.T) {
//     FolderPreCondition()
     request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body) //Q: HOW TO CREATE THE BODY ACCEPTABLE BY THE ABOVE HANDLER FUNC?
//     SOME ASSERTION LOGIC
}
```

Comment: You have to abstract out (mock) not related dependencies. In your case, you might  want to mock the directory's content.

Comment: "How can I pass a folder" - you wouldn't pass a directory (folder) to test your handler, because that's not what your handler takes in normally. That's what your *JavaScript* works with. Your handler just receives a set of files, which is what it should be tested against.

Answer (score 3):

You should write your file to request:

```
func newFileUploadRequest(url string, paramName, path string) (*http.Request, error) {
file, err := os.Open(path)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

defer file.Close()

body := new(bytes.Buffer)

writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(paramName, filepath.Base(path))

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

_, err = io.Copy(part, file)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

err = writer.Close()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, body)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

req.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

return req, err
```

}

then use it:

```
    req, err := newFileUploadRequest("http://localhost:1234/upload", "multiplefiles", path)

client := &http.Client{}

resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

It works for me, hope it helps you)